# Reading input file with JSInterop from Blazor

Tags: javascript, interop, blazor

Hello i am trying to load a file from local storage using the `FileReader` api.
I have tested the `js` method directly in a `HTML` page and it works.

However when calling it from `Blazor` - `JSRuntime` i get the following error :

```
'Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
```

**JS**

```
window.methods = {
    fileChange:function(event) {
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        console.log("file retrieved");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            console.log(reader.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file); 
    }
}
```

**CSHTML**

```
<input  type="file" onchange="@(async(x)=>await onFileChange(x))"/>
public async Task onFileChange(UIChangeEventArgs ev) {
            var str=await JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<string>("methods.fileChange", ev.Value);
        }
```

**P.S**
So according to the error , the method is called successfully but it receives an undefined.Do i need to do a cast or something when i use `InvokeAsync` ?

I need to get the content of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JavaScript interops to solve this problem. There are already NuGet packages available for dealing with this. For a live video demonstration of the answer please see my video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-IuZQeZ10Uw&t=12s

In the video a NuGet package called Blazor.FileReader is used for JavaScript interop. With Blazor.FileRead I was able to read an `input` creating a data URI and uploading it to Azure Cognitive Services. You can see the code below.

```
@using Blazor.FileReader
@using System.IO;
@using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision.Models;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

@page "/fetchdata"
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject IFileReaderService fileReaderService;

<h1>Cognitive Services Vision</h1>

<input type="file" id="fileUpload" ref="fileUpload" onchange="@UploadFile" />

<img src="@imageData" style="@( analysis != null ? $"border: 5px solid #{analysis.Color.AccentColor}" : "" )" />

@if (analysis == null)
{
    <p>Select an image</p>
}
else
{
    <p>@analysis.Description.Captions.First().Text</p>
    <p>@analysis.Color.AccentColor</p>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var tag in analysis.Tags)
        {
            <li>@tag.Name</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
@functions {

    ElementRef fileUpload;
    string imageData = String.Empty;
    ImageAnalysis analysis;

    async Task UploadFile()
    {
        var files = await fileReaderService.CreateReference(fileUpload).EnumerateFilesAsync();

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = await files.First().CreateMemoryStreamAsync())
        {
            byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

            imageData = $"data:image/jpg;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)}";
            var response = await Http.PostAsync(
                    requestUri: "api/SampleData/Save",
                    content: new ByteArrayContent(bytes)
                );
            analysis = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImageAnalysis>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Though i was looking for a more `raw` approach , to see how to  `DYI` the interop part.

Comment: For a "raw" approach just use the source code of Blazor.FileReader https://github.com/Tewr/BlazorFileReader

Answer (score 1):

Buddy, why do you treat the passed parameter to the fileChange function as if it was an event object? It is not. Look again at your code, ev.Value is not the event object. It is a string value of the file name. Try this instead:

```
window.methods = {
    fileChange:function(fileName) {

        console.log("file retrieved: " + fileName);

 }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I need to get the  content of file not the name.

Comment: I know very well what you want to do, and already told you so. Read my previous answer as well. Once again,  the value of UIChangeEventArgs.Value is the file name. Right. Now, you should pass this file to the fileChange function. See my current answer above. This function has a single string parameter which is, once again, the file name provided to you by UIChangeEventArgs.Value. Now use the FileReader API to read the contents of the file. Read my first answer above. Try to do it yourself. If you won't succeed, create a new question, displaying your code, and I'll solve the issue for you.

Comment: Well this is what i am trying to do , to read the contents of the `FileReader` api. Your answer indeed provides the `filename` but as you can see in my post that i tried using the `FileReader` api.

Comment: this is not the answer because it does not provide the contents of the file, only the filename.

Comment: @Rich Bryant, This is the answer... I've told him exactly why he gets the error. It is still there ( in his question), though he has updated his original question  later on. See my comment above. His question was not about how to read the contents of the file. It was,again, about the error.